# Is it possible to specify depth in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

I am using the MigLayout library for a Swing GUI.

I would like to overlay two JPanel, as so:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  |         2             |
|    |                       |
+----+                       |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
```

much like a [minimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-map) in a video game.

---

It seems to me there are two ways to achieve this:

**JLayeredPane**

```
JPanel main = new JPanel();
main.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
// ... fill it with Swing components ...
JPanel minimap = new JPanel();
minimap.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
/// ... fill it with Swing components ...
JLayeredPane layer = new JLayeredPane();
layer.add(main, new Integer(0));
layer.add(minimap, new Integer(1));
```

This approach, however, is flimsy because I have to specify `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`. If the window is resized, then it seems like I have to calculate these values again.

**JLayeredPane & MigLayout**

```
JPanel main = new JPanel();
// ... fill it with Swing components ...
JPanel minimap = new JPanel();
/// ... fill it with Swing components ...
JLayeredPane layer = new JLayeredPane();
layer.setLayoutManager(new MigLayout());

CC positioning;

positioning = // ??? something specified in percents and z-order?
layer.add(main, positioning, new Integer(0));

positioning = // ??? something specified in percents and z-order?
layer.add(minimap, positioning, new Integer(1));
```

Is it possible to fill in the positioning code with something that allows for overlays using MigLayout while letting me specify percent values (as opposed to the pixel resolution `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` in the first example)?

**EDIT**:

Here is a solution that *partially* works:

```
positioning = new CC().width("100%").height("100%");
// ...
positioning = new CC().pos("10", "10");
```

However, the display jitters and sometimes is invisible. I believe this has to do with an indeterminate rendering order (although that's just intuition).

Comment: I've also tried setComponentZOrder, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've also tried setComponentZOrder, but that doesn't seem to have any effect

I don't know how MigLayout works behind the scenes but I would think ZOrder is important.

Check out the [Overlap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) which uses ZOrder for laying out components and has a little blurb on my understanding of how ZOrder works.

Maybe the **isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()** method, as mentioned in the article, is also important is this case,

Comment: Robert D. Camick, you solved my problem! I had to override isOptmizedDrawingEnabled to return false, and add the minimap first.