# Is it possible to overlay a JPanel on top of another?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, overlay

I am attempting to overlay a smaller panel (`sub`) over a larger panel (`parent`). The dimensions of sub are smaller than that of parent.

```
JPanel sub = new JPanel();
JPanel parent = new CustomPanel();
```

I would like to override parent's `paintComponent` method to draw sub in the top left hand corner with an offset of 5 pixels from the top and left sides. It would look something like this:

```
class CustomPanel extends JPanel() {

    JPanel sub = null;

    public CustomPanel(JPanel sub) {
        this.sub = sub;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        this.paintComponent(g);
        // TODO: Here is where I would call something like sub.paint();
        // However, I want sub to "start its paint" 5 pixels inside of
        // parent's dimensions. How do I specify this?
```

Is it possible to tell sub to paint itself at a specific location? Terrible idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just `setLayout(null)` on the parent panel and then, before adding the sub panel to parent , set it's position and dimensions using it's `setBounds` method. This way there is no need to use `paintComponent` for positioning the sub panel.

Is case you parent panel should have specific layout with other components and sub should overlay all that, look into [JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)(Java 7) / [JXLayer](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/)(Java 6).

Third solution can be using [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html).

Comment: The problem being that `parent` contains a non-trivial layout of components as well. The overlay (`sub`) should draw over them - but I don't think I can get away from positioning them all manually.

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers - I have played with LayeredPane before but it's been a little while and I can't instantly recall why I was having troubles with it. I'll try it again, but hopefully there's also a way to perform the paint manually.

Comment: With JLayer you can paint over the parent panel

Comment: You were right and I apologize - this is a duplicate. I had this problem in February as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779401/is-it-possible-to-specify-depth-in-miglayout